# Eclipseで getter/setter のコメントを生成するには？

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipseを使用してJavaの開発を行っています。

以前使用していたEclipse(Pleiades All in One 4.3 Keplarにて確認)では、[編集]->[選択したフィールドのGetter/Setter]で
フィールドのjavadocを参照しGetter/Setterのコメントを生成してくれていました。

通常のEclipseにプラグインを導入して同じことをしたいのですが、実現する方法を教えて頂けませんでしょうか。

4.3では下記のフィールドから…

```
    /** 氏名 */
    private String shimei;
```

下記のGetter/Setterを生成してくれていました。
ポイントはフィールドのjavadocに記載した日本語「氏名」をGetter/Setterのコメントに使用してくれるところです。

```
    /**
     * 氏名を取得します。
     * @return 氏名
     */
    public String getShimei() {
        return shimei;
    }
    
    /**
     * 氏名を設定します。
     * @param shimei 氏名
     */
    public void setShimei(String shimei) {
        this.shimei = shimei;
    }
```